# the correct way to use "who" in sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

I'm little bit confused with these sentences

> People who dont have purpose are prone to addictions.
>   People who dont have purpose prone to addictions.

Which one is correct?

> People who always late are idiots.
>   People who are always late idiots.

Which one is correct ?

Comment: Of the four, only one is correct: "People who don't have purpose are prone to addictions."  The last two are both incorrect.  It should be "People who are always late are idiots."

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is correct? (First question)

People who don't have purpose are prone to addictions.

> Which one is correct? (Second question)

Neither. The correct sentence would be "People who are always late are idiots."

Comment: And what do you call people who answer this sort of question, given the stated aims of SE EL&U?